# what would happen if I new a Local<Value> without a HandleScope in V8?

Tags: node.js, v8

is that allowed? Or what would happen if I do this.
Would this handle not be tracked by GC, or tracked by GC but not released?

In v8.h:

```
 /**
 * A stack-allocated class that governs a number of local handles.
 * After a handle scope has been created, all local handles will be
 * allocated within that handle scope until either the handle scope is
 * deleted or another handle scope is created.  If there is already a
* handle scope and a new one is created, all allocations will take
* place in the new handle scope until it is deleted.  After that,
 * new handles will again be allocated in the original handle scope.
*
* After the handle scope of a local handle has been deleted the
* garbage collector will no longer track the object stored in the
* handle and may deallocate it.  The behavior of accessing a handle
* for which the handle scope has been deleted is undefined.
*/
class V8_EXPORT HandleScope {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V8 blows up.   if you're running a debug build you'll get a nicer error message, but it will crash.

Something about "check_api_usage" or something like that.

I've seen that message too many times.

If you need to hold on to a javascript value longer than a lexical scope, you need to put it into a (more expensive) `v8::Global<T>` object instead.  Note that `global`s are move-only, similar to a unique_ptr.